# Delphi Syntax error in FROM clause, but no from clause

Tags: sql, database, delphi, syntax-error

I'm really new to Delphi and have not yet worked with SQL (I'm a complete beginner).

I use code to connect my database and tables to my program, but as soon as I run my program, I get a `Syntax error in FROM clause` message.

When I select break, it highlights `end;` of a part of the code.

```
function TADOCommand.Execute(var RecordsAffected: Integer;
  const Parameters: OleVariant): _Recordset;
var
  VarRecsAffected: OleVariant;
begin
  SetConnectionFlag(cfExecute, True);
  try
    Initialize;
    Result := CommandObject.Execute(VarRecsAffected, Parameters,
              Integer(CommandObject.CommandType) + ExecuteOptionsToOrd
              (FExecuteOptions));
    RecordsAffected := VarRecsAffected;
  finally
    SetConnectionFlag(cfExecute, False);
  end;
end;
```

I have three tables, of which two display on their grids, but one is not displaying on the grid, and also gives me the `Syntax error in FROM clause` when I want to do anything with it.

This is the code that I used to connect my database in the datamodule:

```
unit dmChamps_u;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, ADODB, DB; // add Ado and DB

type
  TdmChamps = class(TDataModule)
    procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    conArchers: TADOConnection;
    tblArchers: TADOTable;
    tblJT: TADOTable;
    tblMatches: TADOTable;
    dscArchers: TDataSource;
    dscMatches: TDataSource;
    dscJT: TDataSource;
  end;

var
  dmChamps: TdmChamps;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TdmChamps.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // create objects
  conArchers := TADOConnection.Create(dmChamps);
  tblArchers := TADOTable.Create(dmChamps);
  tblMatches := TADOTable.Create(dmChamps);
  tblJT := TADOTable.Create(dmChamps);
  dscArchers := TDataSource.Create(dmChamps);
  dscMatches := TDataSource.Create(dmChamps);
  dscJT := TDataSource.Create(dmChamps);

  // setup connection
  conArchers.ConnectionString :=
    'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=ArchChampsDB.mdb;Mode=ReadWrite;Persist Security Info=False';
  conArchers.LoginPrompt := false;
  conArchers.Open;

  // setup table archers
  tblArchers.Connection := conArchers;
  tblArchers.TableName := 'Archers';
  // setup data source
  dscArchers.DataSet := tblArchers;
  tblArchers.Open;

  // setup table matches
  tblMatches.Connection := conArchers;
  tblMatches.TableName := 'Matches';
  // setup data source
  dscMatches.DataSet := tblMatches;
  tblMatches.Open;

  // setup table JT
  tblJT.Connection := conArchers;
  tblJT.TableName := 'Judges/Timekeepers';
  // setup data source
  dscJT.DataSet := tblJT;
  tblJT.Open;

end;

end.
```

I've looked through all of the questions on the `From clause` error already on the site, but none of the scenarios quite match my problem. I also went to Embarcadero's site and read about TableDirect, which I thought might be a possible solution, but it was already in the code.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted will produce the error you describe, which means it's happening somewhere else in code you have NOT provided. There's nothing in that code that would cause `TADOCommand.Execute` to be called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here

```
 tblJT.TableName := 'Judges/Judges';
```

You can't has a table with that name, or Judges or Timekeepers

You can solve do it:

```
 // setup table J
  tblJT.Connection := conArchers;
  tblJT.TableName := 'Judges';
  // setup data source
  dscJT.DataSet := tblJT;
  tblJT.Open;
```

Separated

```
// setup table T
  tblJT.Connection := conArchers;
  tblJT.TableName := 'Timekeepers';
  // setup data source
  dscJT.DataSet := tblJT;
  tblJT.Open;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is because of the slash in 'Judges/Timekeepers'.

Did you try to debug step by step going to the code in `DataModuleCreate`?

Comment: This is a comment to the original question, not an answer. *Maybe it is* and *Did you try* are suggestions, not answers.